# get_next_post() and get_previous_post() return wrong posts

Tags: posts, loop, navigation, get-posts

I’ve been trying to retrieve the next and previous post in one of my Wordpress templates. Please note that I want to get the full post object instead of just the pre-formatted links to the posts.

The problem I face is that whenever I call these functions wrong posts are returned. They are in the same post type, but they are off by like a few ids (say 3/4).

```
// Get next and previous link
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
       var_dump($post);
       var_dump(get_previous_post());
   }
}
```

The first variable dump returns me the correct post object. The second one returns a page that's around 4 IDs (they range from 64 - 60) off...

I tried calling the functions both with and without parameters, it returned false posts in both situations.

Hope someone has an answer.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please note that I’m on a single page. My code is get_next_post() for recieving my next post and get_previous_post() for the previous one, as I explained above. It’s litterly these two lines, not more.

Comment: These functions rely on the global `$post` to contain the correct post that you are trying to fetch next/prev from, verify that this contains the correct post object. A secondary query can overwrite this value if it's not reset correctly.

Comment: when I `var_dump($post)` it returns me the correct object

Comment: `if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post();
    var_dump($post);
    var_dump(get_previous_post());
 }`

Ran this code, the first `var_dump()` gave me the correct information, the second gave me an ID that was around 4 pages off... So strange

Comment: Just to be clear: You're aware that IDs are not necessarily consecutive right? The adjacent post to post 12 could easily be post 16, or 100, or 1000, depending on what other content has been added to the site. IDs are shared by revisions, other post types, media, and menu items. So if you add a post, and it gets ID 60, but then you upload 2 images, and make a revision, the next post you add will be 64. These functions are intended to get the next published post in chronological order based on post date.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you read my post I explain that they actually are consecutive

Comment: Just to clear things out, I'm calling the functions on a single posts' page, for instance `/store/first-store/` which has the ID of `64`. `get_next_post()` returns a false which is correct. `get_previous_post()` gives me a post with the ID of `60` whilst the post with the ID of `63` should've been the one that was returned.

Comment: Also, it's the only function that I'm calling, so there are no other posts being requested. The `$post` variable returns the correct post and ID.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jacob, I've imported the posts from a different CMS which means that some of the dates are off.. like a few seconds, which fucks up the ID structure

Comment: System doesn't allow me to commment, excuse the post as "answer". I had a similar problem, because I used a plugin to duplicate the same post, for development purposes. As a result all posts had the same publish date. Changing the publish date of each post worked for me too. (same as Jim's answer)

Comment: @LSE I converted your _answer_ into a comment, but keep in mind that this is how the sites automation finds spambots and bans them, it is a **very** risky thing to do, don't do it. As a 1 rep user it doesn't take much to get the 20 reputation needed to comment, and as a moderator I can't guarantee that I can step in and save the day if you do it again

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Wordpress uses these functions based on `post_date` ...

I did an import from an old CMS to Wordpress where I just added all posts within a loop. Some of the dates were a few seconds off. This caused the functions to return 'false' posts.

I actually wrote a custom class that handles `getNext()` and `getPrevious()` with a combined function called `getSiblings()` based on `post_id`.

I actually wrote a class that fully tackles this problem. Check [github](https://github.com/jrtderonde/wp-post-siblings) for the full code. Contribution would be very much appreciated :-)